# Why does Git subtree process the same commits over and over?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I extracted a subtree from a large repo using `git subtree split` and pushed it to another remote.
I can successfully pull commits from that subtree remote. 
However, when I'm trying to push changes from main project to subtree I see somthing like

```
C:\Dev\projects\myproject>git subtree push -P services/myService subtree-repo master
git push using:  subtree-repo master
227/400 (226)
```

So all commits since `subtree split` are processed to identify what to push. If 2 commits out of 400 where related to services/myService, than only these 2are pushed, so this is correct behaviour.

However, processing 400 commits takes a lot of time, and this number can dramatically increase up to several thousands in a month, so every single push will take an hour or so. That is unacceptable.

I tried to resolve it by myself and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27155706/4007478). 
Shortly, it advises to use `git subtree split` with `--rejoin` flag, so merge commit with subtree reference will be generated, and next push only commits since that merge will be processed.

Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. Executing git subtree split

```
C:\Dev\projects\myproject>git subtree split --rejoin -P services/myService
4/400 (3)
```

Finishes successfully:

```
C:\Dev\projects\myproject>git subtree split --rejoin -P services/myService
Already up-to-date.
0e50cea87309b1ec79a00113165d9db2baa8f862
```

but goes through **all commits** again and again (and git `subtree push also`).

What is interesting, executing the same command in Git Bash returns an error.

```
$ git subtree split --rejoin -P services/myService
C:/Users/myUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-subtree: line 751: 
14516 Done                    eval "$grl"
      17364 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) | while read rev parents; do
     process_split_commit "$rev" "$parents" 0;
done
```

So could you please help to find an answer how to make `git subtree` **not** to go through all commits since subtree adding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reduce the ever-increasing time to push a subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134975/how-can-i-reduce-the-ever-increasing-time-to-push-a-subtree)

Comment: Hi @AnthonyMastrean, unfortunately no, for some reason rejoin iterates through the same commits over and over again.